# Page layout: is my website too "sober"?

Tags: page-layout

My website here:

http://www.papdevis.fr/

is very, very (x 14) "sober", i.e. there's the *less* menus I could do.

If you click on a region, same thing: there's the *less* menus I could do:

Mes devis | Recherche avancée | Offres et demandes  |  Offres uniquement  |  Demandes uniquement

which means:

My quotes | Advanced search | Offers and requests | Offers only | Requests only

I've been told a lot of times that there should be more: the "home" button (which is the banner: click on the banner), the breadcrumb, and so on.

What do you think?

Comment: You should read FAQ : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Pankaj I noticed these comments on many questions.  It is good guidance, but would be more helpful if you let people know which part of the FAQ you think is most relevant.

Comment: Olivier-  I'm closing this because I can't really discern what guidance you are seeking.  If you can please edit this question to be more specific and flag it for mod attention, we can reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks great with less menu items then having a lot. Since it confuses the viewer.

Nothing is wrong with *not* having a **Home** button, the banner works perfectly. 
Everyone nowadays is familier with it,

like in the case of Facebook,

> I dont press **Home** button on right-side to move to my *News Feed*, I press **Facebook** on left side.:)

Your website menu is perfect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Are you saying this because (sorry for that it's not about you I don't know you, but it's about some people that act like that): did you provide your own opinion, or did you say something based on real facts and recommandations? If so, may I ask you to provide some links for me to read? Thank you very much!

Comment: Its **fine**, I presented my views over it, but its what many people thinks, _try reading this_ [link](http://dot5.drawar.com/posts/is-a-home-link-necessary)